# How to display file upload progress in progressbar - Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I would like to display file upload progress in a  progress bar on my web page while uploading a file to  Amazon S3 …

On my web page I select a file from a file input which calls my controller with a Ajax POST request .

In the controller I extract the file from the posted request.

```
var hpf = Request.Files[1];
```

Then I call a method that uses the AmazonS3Client..

```
UploadVideoMultiPart(hpf.InputStream,fileName)
```

This above method completes the upload to S3 perfectly fine and  during that process repeatedly sends the number bytes uploaded  .

```
public static void UploadPartProgressEventCallback(object sender, StreamTransferProgressArgs e)
        {// Process event. 
            Var progress = (string.Format("{0}/{1}", e.TransferredBytes, totalContentLength));
        }
```

Example:

TransferredBytes    TotalBytes

8778          152652556

2562          152652556

How can I send back the data from the UploadPartProgressEventCallback to the browser without stopping the upload thread.

**If I could get  this data I would be able to update my progress bar.**

Comment: If you use ajax and upload directly to s3 from the browser you would show a progress bar.

Comment: @user1526912 you can check the Transfereed bytes at client side using `xhr.upload.onprogress` right /

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You Need something to communicate between your Server to Client

[SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/) is your saviour here in this situation ,with the help of SignalR you gains the ability to push the Content from server side to Clientside.

entire Documentation is here [SignalR@GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki)

you can follow these
[web resources](http://signalr.net/) as well

**(assuming you have gone through above link)**

Now coming back to your need ,

> you can even hook SignalR broadcast ie can call client method and manage
>   groups outside the Hub class

an example beautifully explained here [In this Example](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub)

Although it will be new api to learn if you are not familiar,but trust me it won't take much time to grasp it,

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered uploading your file/s **direct to S3** from your webpage instead of going back to your webserver? (This will enable you to have easier control of your progress bar)

[image: Direct file upload from browser to S3]

Details can be found here:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTExamples.html (Examples)

The following SO article also talks about this in detail

- [Amazon S3 direct file upload from client browser - private key disclosure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585881/amazon-s3-direct-file-upload-from-client-browser-private-key-disclosure)