# How to implement dropzone.js to upload file into Amazon s3 server?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dropzone.js

Please help to implement the dropzone.js to upload the file into Amazon s3 server. Already referred the following link https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/33, but, no idea to implement. kindly help to implement the same. Any dropzone configuration code is required.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For someone who might also jumped into this question, I'd like to share my working scenario (serverlessly with AWS Lambda).

**Note**: A full example can be found in my [Vue S3 Dropzone component](https://github.com/kfei/vue-s3-dropzone/blob/master/frontend/src/components/Dropzone.vue), the code related to Dropzone and S3 are actually framework agnostic.

So, basically,

1. The client (browser) calls an AWS Lambda function to get the pre-signed upload URL for each file being added.
2. When the pre-signed URL returned in response, the client will trigger `dropzone.processFile` immediately.
3. When the file being processing, change `dropzone.options.url` for the file accordingly.

Hints:

- As I'm signing a **PUT** upload-able URL, I'm going to [hijack](https://github.com/kfei/vue-s3-dropzone/blob/e348188/frontend/src/components/Dropzone.vue#L30-L37) the `xhr.send` function, otherwise Dropzone will always send file within formData, which is bad for a PUT upload.

### The final client code

```
// In the `accept` function we request a signed upload URL when a file being accepted
accept (file, done) {
  lambda.getSignedURL(file)
    .then((url) => {
      file.uploadURL = url
      done()
      // And process each file immediately
      setTimeout(() => dropzone.processFile(file))
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      done('Failed to get an S3 signed upload URL', err)
    })
}

// Set signed upload URL for each file being processing
dropzone.on('processing', (file) => {
  dropzone.options.url = file.uploadURL
})
```

### The final AWS Lambda code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
// Make sure you set this env variable correctly
var bucketName = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    if (!event.hasOwnProperty('contentType')) {
        context.fail({ err: 'Missing contentType' })
    }

    if (!event.hasOwnProperty('filePath')) {
        context.fail({ err: 'Missing filePath' })
    }

    var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: event.filePath,
        Expires: 3600,
        ContentType: event.contentType
    }

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, (err, url) => {
        if (err) {
            context.fail({ err })
        } else {
            context.succeed({ url })
        }
    })
}
```

### Demo

[image: demo-gif]

Comment: This saved me so much trouble. Thank you!

Comment: You mention on the code that the `header` must be updated for each file but it doesn't look like you do that, how and where is this done?

Comment: You saved my day. The bounty will be awarded to you tomorrow, thank you so much

Comment: @KF Lin - i know i'm responding to a very old thread, but i wanted to check whether your solution comes from a pre-Cognito world or post-Cognito world. If using a Cognito identity, do we still need to have a Lambda function generating signed URLs?

Comment: @JimitRaithatha I believe the usefulness of Cognito is not requiring the `key` or filename at the time of generating the signature.

Comment: for someone new to aws, how do you set up the api gateway to run that lambda function?