# Direct file upload to S3 using sigv4

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm looking for a secure way to directly upload large files to S3 (for performance issue).

After few hours of research, I've come to the (maybe incorrect) conclusion that I should use "Browser-Based Uploads Using POST".
As referenced in this thread:
[Amazon S3 direct file upload from client browser - private key disclosure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585881/amazon-s3-direct-file-upload-from-client-browser-private-key-disclosure)

Before trying this directly, I thought about making a cURL POC with direct upload and signature computation.
I've failed to make it work, and **haven't found a successful POC on the web using Authentification Version 4 manual settings.**

My signature is OK. 
The only issue is that Amazon is double SHA256ing my file content and is thus not validation my x-amz-content-sha-256 header.

- lower(SHA256(e8379a31b13fb9423928fe28dd41a5e3204a52072634503c31e8b3ea42605b46))
  = 4fa84cd7d18e0d33dbd62d0492eca4a159e122391ae0a3e636bd3cf527680c87

**I'm not sure of understanding what should I put in my cURL and canonical request payload (and the linked content-length value) and the x-amz-content-sha-256 header.
Should it all be the same values ?**
If yes, then the Amazon doc specifies it should all be encrypted to SHA256, so I've no idea why Amazon reSHA256 my already SHA256 payload...

Error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch</Code>
<Message>The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed.</Message><ClientComputedContentSHA256>e8379a31b13fb9423928fe28dd41a5e3204a52072634503c31e8b3ea42605b46</ClientComputedContentSHA256><S3ComputedContentSHA256>4fa84cd7d18e0d33dbd62d0492eca4a159e122391ae0a3e636bd3cf527680c87</S3ComputedContentSHA256>
<RequestId>419A185269B0F891</RequestId><HostId>QHWxK0Mzz6AfG44ypXBti3W0tYx1xkG9lZGqc2kUKyMF9STwP18M3racio0k06aH5+1ok/Irdn8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

cURL command:

```
curl 
-v https://??.s3.amazonaws.com/recordtest/test.jpg        
-H "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=??/20170228/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=43750caa762314eb70aace1f7f8ae34633b93352aa25646433ef21e48dd79429"        -H "Content-Length: 64"        
-H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"        
-H "x-amz-content-sha256: e8379a31b13fb9423928fe28dd41a5e3204a52072634503c31e8b3ea42605b46"        
-H "x-amz-date: 20170228T111828Z"        
-d "e8379a31b13fb9423928fe28dd41a5e3204a52072634503c31e8b3ea42605b46"        
-X PUT
```

Generated canonical request:

```
PUT
/recordtest/test.jpg

content-length:64
content-type:application/octet-stream
host:??.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:e8379a31b13fb9423928fe28dd41a5e3204a52072634503c31e8b3ea42605b46
x-amz-date:20170228T111200Z

content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
e8379a31b13fb9423928fe28dd41a5e3204a52072634503c31e8b3ea42605b46
```

---

Comment: Using `-d "e8379a31b13fb9423928fe28dd41a5e3204a52072634503c31e8b3ea42605b46"`, you are telling curl that this string of digits is the request body -- this is the content of the file (object) that you want to upload.  That is almost certainly not what you intend to do, but explains exactly why the sha256 error occurs.  The canonical request is a canonical *representation* of the request.  You wouldn't actually transmit that last line (e8379a...) in the request you send.  I believe you actually want `--data-binary '@local_file_name'`.

Comment: Note also for reference that SHA256 is not encryption, it's a cryptographic hash, which is a vastly different thing than encryption.

Comment: I've replaced my cURL command and added --data-binary "@./img/$img_file" and I've now got this error: *GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.

Comment: And now : curl : (55) Failed sending data to the peer

Comment: And if I retry enough times, I occasionaly get the samer error as before (the provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed)... Should I modify something else than the binary payload of the cURL request ? Like the content-length ?

Comment: Yes, the `Content-Length` header in the request and in the signing process needs to be set to the size of the file to be uploaded, in bytes.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Setting both Content-Length header to the byte length of the non-hashed file made it work. I will try a "real" XmlHttpRequest POST now...