# Upload file to Amazon s3 - client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I trying upload a file to Amazon s3

This is the params that i send
[params send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx2vS.png)

and the api return this error of permiss
[error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3njqV.png)

This are my cors configuration

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>ETags</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-acl</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>      
</CORSRule>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585881/amazon-s3-direct-file-upload-from-client-browser-private-key-disclosure?rq=1

Comment: I using  AWS.S3 javascript api, and this allow accessKeyId and secretAccessKey, and if no send the params ACL and GrandFullControl all do fine, but if i send this two params, i get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is "Specifying both canned ACLs and Header Grants is not allowed". (FYI for future posts, please include the error message directly in your question)

When putting an object, you can supply either a canned ACL or a specific grant/grantee, but not both. You have supplied both.

If your goal is to allow read by *any* authenticated user, then just use the canned ACL option of authenticated-read. That will give the object owner FULL_CONTROL and will give the AuthenticatedUsers group READ access. See [Canned ACLS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) for more details.

PS you're also using GrantFullControl incorrectly. Its value needs to be a grantee, not a permission string such as 'READ'.